# Install or Update Android App Programmatically android 8

Tags: android-8.0-oreo, android-fileprovider, android-8.1-oreo

I am trying to install an app from my app programmatically on an **android 8 (Oreo)** device.

am using the below code that leads to this problem.
My File provider authority is defined as

```
`private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.unicornialab.myapplication.fileprovider";`
```

The app i am trying to install is located at folder named Alpha1updates at the root storage of my device like in first this line

```
`File toInstall = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                        +  File.separator + "Alpha1Updates" + File.separator, "update.apk")`
```

And then i try to install the app like shown below

```
`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
           // Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.unicornialab.myapplication", newFile);
            Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, AUTHORITY, toInstall);
//            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
//            intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
            intent.setData(apkUri);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Uri apkUri = Uri.fromFile(toInstall);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }`
```

Since i am using android 8 device, the code at

```
`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {}`
```

in the above code is executed.
I have requested for permissions to install packages from unknown sources like so

```
`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            if (!getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls()) {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES).setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", getPackageName()))), MY_PERMISSIONS_INSTALLFROM_UNKWONSOURCES);
            }
        }`
```

My manifest file i have included a provider like so.

```
`<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>`
```

My provider_paths at the xml folder is like below

```
`<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>`
```

What might i be doing wrong to get that **There was a problem parsing the package**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 2):

In this issue you should add this permission for android **oreo**

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

And for provider class i generated a class *GenericFileProvider*  like this:

```
public class GenericFileProvider extends FileProvider {

private static final String TAG_EXTERNAL_FILES = "external-files-path";
private static final String TAG_EXTERNAL_CACHE = "external-cache-path";

private static final String TAG_ROOT_PATH = "root-path";
private static final String TAG_FILES_PATH = "files-path";
private static final String TAG_CACHE_PATH = "cache-path";
private static final String TAG_EXTERNAL = "external-path";}
```

And this is my *xml* code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="external_files" path="./"/>
</paths>
```

in this issue i think your address of directory in get app is wrong adn you should try to 
fix that.